# Where can I see the detailed historical data for a specified stock?

Tags: stocks, historical-data

I can find very detailed trading prices via Google Finance for the past 5 days. But for a older moment, Google Finance just can't provide. For example, I want to see the price of `TWTR` when it's first public offering begins and its next 48 hours. What should I do?

Update: I meant to see the data within a day (hourly or even minutely data)

Thanks,

Comment: You can always hit a library's newspaper archives... or see if the newspaper has online archives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To see a chart with 1-minute data for a stock on a specific date:

- Go to [Trading Physics](http://www.tradingphysics.org/Charts/ViewIndicatorsChart.aspx)
- Enter the stock symbol in the "Stock ticker" field
- Select a date
- Select "1 Day" for the "Days on chart" field
- Click the Submit button

For example, here is the chart for TWTR on November 7, 2013 - the day of the IPO:

[image]

Here is the chart for TWTR on November 8, 2013 - its second day of trading:

[image]

Here is the chart for TWTR on November 11, 2013 - its third day of trading:

[image]

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo I edited my answer to include a chart for each of TWTR's first three trading days.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo Finance's Historical Prices section allows you to look up  daily historical quotes for any given stock symbol, you don't have to hit a library for this information.

Your can choose a desired time frame for your query, and the dataset will include High/Low/Close/Volume numbers. You can then download a CSV version of this report and perform additional analysis in a spreadsheet of your choice.

Below is Twitter report from IPO through yesterday:

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=TWTR&a=10&b=7&c=2013&d=08&e=23&f=2014&g=d

Comment: Thanks but I can't check out the details within the first day, right?

Comment: You are absolutely correct in that assumption.